# How does using dynamic colors in viewDidLoad automatically switch the colors for Dark mode?

Tags: ios-darkmode

Per my understanding of the WWDC 2019 video "Implementing Dark Mode in iOS", dynamic colors are resolved using `UITraitCollection.current`. The updated trait collection is ready only in certain methods such as `draw`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` etc.

So, if I use dynamic colors inside viewDidLoad, for example, the colors should not update automatically upon mode switch. However, they *are* being updated

Below is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 20))
    label.textColor = UIColor.label
    label.text = "Label text"

    view.addSubview(label)
  }
}
```

The way I switched the mode in the simulator was Settings -> Developer -> Dark appearance. Then I brought my app to the foreground.

How did the color get auto-updated?

Note: I did not test in my device.

Answer (score 3):

The colors you are using, `systemBackground` and `label`, are actually *dynamic colors* that adopt automatically when the trait collection changes. (Ok, under the hood it's more likely that the views that apply the colors react to trait environment changes and re-evaluate the colors.) That's why you don't need to do anything manually when using the system colors.

If you want the same behavior for your own colors, you have two options:

You can create a color set in an asset catalog. In color sets, you can define different colors for different appearances (light & dark mode and high-contrast accessibility colors). You can them get the color by the name of your color set in code (`UIColor(named:)`) or use them in interface builder.

Alternatively, you can use a dynamic provider block when creating the color in code, where you can determine the actual color based on the trait collection:

```
let color = UIColor { traitCollection -> UIColor in
    switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
        case .light, .unspecified: return .white
        case .dark: return .black
    }
}
```